# database development environment, MySql

Tags: mysql, database-design, replication

I need to create copy/replication of our **databases** for the development environment.

I'm not sure how to do it. DBs are updating many times during a day; not only new records added but also  old records are updated.

How should I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

The *"right answer"* is highly application dependant, but here are a few strategies I've seen used before.

**Daily Backup / Restore-on-demand**

This works well if you have a small data set, and the need to be able to have various developers use the backups ad-hoc. The idea is basically a mysqldump on a replication target system and some scripts to do a MySQL import.

**Binary Log Replication**

This method probably won't work for you, as you specifically want to read and write to the development database. Sometimes people will use replication to run read-only regression testing against, but modifying the database will result in failed replication and/or inconsistent data.

[https://serverfault.com/questions/380701/replicate-main-mysql-db-to-a-development-server-to-play-with-real-data]

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, a regular backup or dump, plus an on-demand restore gives your Developers the most flexibility, being able to refresh their databases as and when they please.

However, under GDPR, the use of Live data in non-Live systems really ought to be covered by your organisation's Privacy Notice.  Check with your Data Protection Officer (or equivalent) or your legal department about whether you're even *allowed* to use Live data in non-Live systems.

If so; great.

If *not* then you have [a lot of] work to do in "masking" that Live data *before* it gets anywhere near a Developer, so as to close off that vector for Data Breaches.  That will probably involve dumping/restoring the database to a "staging" area, then masking the data somehow and then dumping the resulting database for [safe] use by Developers.